# MS Access - how to rank with 3 variables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to rank using 3 variables from the sample data below:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Case Number | Doc Type | Document Number | Rank   |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
|           1 | A        |         3787104 |    1   |
|           1 | B        |         3786773 |    2   |
|           2 | A        |         3787505 |    1   |
|           3 | A        |         3787525 |    1   |
|           3 | B        |         3786892 |    3   |
|           3 | A        |         3786891 |    2   |
|           4 | B        |         3787514 |    3   |
|           4 | B        |         3787513 |    2   |
|           4 | A        |         3787512 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786436 |    6   |
|           5 | A        |         3786499 |    5   |
|           5 | A        |         3786456 |    4   |
|           5 | A        |         3786371 |    3   |
|           5 | A        |         3786481 |    2   |
|           6 | A        |         3786815 |    1   |
|           7 | B        |         3786998 |    3   |
|           7 | B        |         3786989 |    2   |
|           7 | A        |         3786988 |    1   |
|           8 | B        |         3787033 |    4   |
|           8 | A        |         3787078 |    2   |
|           8 | B        |         3787037 |    3   |
|           8 | A        |         3787074 |    1   |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

First Rank by Group, Then by Doc Type, Then by Document Number.
Here's what I currently have after looking through some of the entries here:

```
SELECT [Case Number], [Doc Type], [Document Number], (
  SELECT  COUNT(*)  from [Document Tracker] AS tbl2 WHERE
(
   tbl1.[Doc Type] < tbl2.[Doc Type] AND
   tbl1.[Case Number] = tbl2.[Case Number] 
)
)
+1 AS Rank
FROM [Document Tracker] AS tbl1
ORDER BY [Case Number], [Doc Type] DESC , [Document Number];
```

This gives me this output:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Case Number | Doc Type | Document Number | Rank   |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
|           1 | A        |         3787104 |    1   |
|           1 | B        |         3786773 |    2   |
|           2 | A        |         3787505 |    1   |
|           3 | A        |         3787525 |    1   |
|           3 | B        |         3786892 |    3   |
|           3 | A        |         3786891 |    1   |
|           4 | B        |         3787514 |    3   |
|           4 | B        |         3787513 |    3   |
|           4 | A        |         3787512 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786436 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786499 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786456 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786371 |    1   |
|           5 | A        |         3786481 |    1   |
|           6 | A        |         3786815 |    1   |
|           7 | B        |         3786998 |    2   |
|           7 | B        |         3786989 |    2   |
|           7 | A        |         3786988 |    1   |
|           8 | B        |         3787033 |    3   |
|           8 | A        |         3787078 |    1   |
|           8 | B        |         3787037 |    3   |
|           8 | A        |         3787074 |    1   |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

I can't figure out the missing code to have it doc numbers ranked as well.
I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: By Group do you mean Case Number? What should the output look like?

Comment: It is not quite clear whether you want the rows numbered by ascending or descending order. The result you are showing does not match your query's `ORDER BY` clause. The ranks you are showing may indicate you want `[Doc Type] ASC, [Document Number] DESC` per `[Case Number]`, but I can't be sure. Anyway, this will be a slight change only to the query I am showing in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to number the rows per [Case Number] ordered by [Doc Type] and [Document Number]. For this to happen, for each row you count the rows before it. These rows must have the same [Case Number], but either the [Doc Type] is lesser or the [Doc Type] is the same and the [Document Number] is lesser.

```
SELECT [Case Number], [Doc Type], [Document Number], 
  (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM [Document Tracker] AS tbl2 
    WHERE tbl1.[Case Number] = tbl2.[Case Number]
    AND 
    (
      tbl1.[Doc Type] < tbl2.[Doc Type]
      OR
      (
        tbl1.[Doc Type] = tbl2.[Doc Type]
        AND
        tbl1.[Document Number] < tbl2.[Document Number]
      )
    )
  ) +1 AS Rank
FROM [Document Tracker] AS tbl1
ORDER BY [Case Number], [Doc Type] DESC , [Document Number];
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor tweak is needed in the filtering and sorting:

```
SELECT 
    [Case Number], 
    [Doc Type], 
    [Document Number], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            [Document Tracker] AS tbl2 
        WHERE
            tbl1.[Doc Type] & CStr(tbl1.[Document Number]) > tbl2.[Doc Type] & CStr(tbl2.[Document Number]) 
            AND
            tbl1.[Case Number] = tbl2.[Case Number]) + 1 AS Rank
FROM 
    [Document Tracker] AS tbl1
ORDER BY 
    [Case Number], 
    [Doc Type] DESC, 
    [Document Number] DESC;
```